# Binding выбранной строки DataGrid в другом DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, binding, mvvm

Есть класс `Book`:

```
class Book
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Authors { get; set; }
  public string Genre { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
}
```

На форме есть два (пусть будут `A` и `B`) DataGrid'a: `A` отображает список объектов `Book`, `B` отображает элементы `Publications` выбранной книги (то есть, привязка к выбранной строке в `A`).

Вопрос в том, как правильно привязаться в `B` к текущей строке в `A`?

Я делаю так, но на мой взгляд это не совсем кошерно:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="BooksGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=WorkingBooksSet, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" // Можно этим воспользоваться?
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="Auto" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Authors}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Genre}" Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>

  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      // Второй DataGrid
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=BooksGrid,                 Path=SelectedItem.Publications}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Publisher}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ISBN}" />
          ...
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>

    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

`WorkingBooksSet` это `ObservableCollection` во ViewModel'e

---

[[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), я, кажется, не понимаю чего-то фундаментального. 
Если пользоваться Вашим способ привязки `ItemsSource={Binding WorkingBooksSet/Publications}`, то я не получу именно выделенную строку в первом `DataGrid`. Надеюсь, Вы меня поняли.

Мой способ мне не нравится тем, что если я изменю имя свойства в модели, то оно не изменится во View, так как у меня привязка:

`ItemSource={Binding ElementName=BooksGrid,Path=SelectedItem.Publications}`

а `SelectedItem` имеет тип `object`, то есть привязанное поле (`ISBN`, например, в моем случае) найдется только во время выполнения.

---

Разобрался. [[[[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), спасибо за помощь и за табличку!

Comment: @VladD, Вы бы свой комментарий преобразовали в ответ. Я бы хоть раз отметил его как верный :)

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Veikedo: Сделано :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что именно вам не нравится в вашем коде?

Я бы правда забиндился как-нибудь так:

```
ItemsSource={Binding WorkingBooksSet/Publications}
```

(но это наверное вкусовщина).

---

Вот вам шпаргалка по binding'ам: http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf

---

Проблема, о которой вы говорите — фундаментальная для WPF. В XAML указывается лишь имя свойства, которое не связано с настоящим типом, и проверяется только на этапе выполнения, а не компиляции. Так было сделано, насколько я понимаю, чтобы избежать зависимости View от нижележащих уровней (VM и модели). Так что исправить её, по идее, невозможно, надо внимательно следить за переименованиями и ошибками binding'а на консоли.

Такие дела.

Comment: Однако если я укажу в привязке конкретный тип (например, как Вы посоветовали), то  по крайней мере ReSharper увидит эти поля и проследит за их изменением.

Comment: @Veikedo: Обычно `Binding` всё равно идёт к `DataContext` (который имеет тип `object`), поэтому проверить наличие и тип поля `WorkingBooksSet` в нём на этапе компиляции невозможно. Интересно, как R# справляется.

Comment: @VladD, R# справляется если `DataContext` указать в самом xaml-файле